# DLL causes "Microsoft Excel has stopped working" but it works fine in Win32 console app

Tags: c++, vba, visual-studio-2012, dll

This will be a long post, but I'm not sure what information is necessary to properly explain this problem.  I have a C++ DLL that I'm trying to call from Excel.  One of the functions causes Excel to crash with a "Microsoft Excel has stopped working" whenever I call it.

The header file:

```
#include <string>

namespace XYZ_ProjectWise
{
    class FileOperator
    {
    public:
        static __declspec(dllexport) long __stdcall initialize(std::string dbName);
        static __declspec(dllexport) long __stdcall openDoc(long projectID,long docID);
    };
}
```

Function code for `initialize()`:

```
long FileOperator::initialize(string dbName)
{
    LPCWSTR user=L"";
    LPCWSTR pwd=L"";
    LPCWSTR schema=L"";
    std::wstring sTemp=std::wstring(dbName.begin(),dbName.end());
    LPCWSTR dbName_L=sTemp.c_str();
    bool resultInit=aaApi_Initialize(AAMODULE_ALL);
    bool resultLogin=aaApi_Login(AAAPIDB_UNKNOWN,dbName_L,user,pwd,schema);
    return 0;
}
```

Output of dumpbin /exports:

```
?initialize@FileOperator@XYZ_ProjectWise@@SGJV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?
$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z
```

Declaration in VBA:

```
Private Declare Function initialize Lib "C:\Program Files
(x86)\Bentley\ProjectWise\bin\XYZ_ProjectWiseDLL.dll" _
Alias "?initialize@FileOperator@XYZ_ProjectWise@@SGJV?$basic_string@DU?
$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z" _
(ByVal dbName As String) As Long
```

How it's being called in VBA:

```
Public Sub testDLL()

Dim result As Long
result = initialize("ABC.DEF.GHI.com:PWOPPID_XYZ")

End Sub
```

What's odd is that the crash does not occur if I include the `initialize()` function code in the `openDoc()` function, with `dbName` hardcoded, and call `openDoc()` by itself as follows:

```
long __stdcall FileOperator::openDoc(long projectID,long docID)
    {

        LPCWSTR dbName=L"ABC.DEF.GHI.com:PWOPPID_XYZ";
        LPCWSTR user=L"";
        LPCWSTR pwd=L"";
        LPCWSTR schema=L"";    
        bool resultInit=aaApi_Initialize(AAMODULE_ALL);    
        bool resultLogin=aaApi_Login(AAAPIDB_UNKNOWN,dbName,user,pwd,schema);

        long resultOpen=aaApi_OpenDocument(projectID,docID,false);
        return resultOpen;
    }
}
```

VBA call:

```
Private Declare Function openDoc Lib "C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Bentley\ProjectWise\bin\XYZ_ProjectWiseDLL.dll" _
Alias "?openDoc@FileOperator@XYZ_ProjectWise@@SGJJJ@Z" _
(ByVal projectID As Long, ByVal docID As Long) As Long

Public Sub testDLL()

Dim result As Long
result = openDoc(1799,29)

End Sub
```

So why does the VBA call to `initialize()` crash, but the same code in the VBA call to `openDoc()` work just fine?

Comment: I am not sure, but I notice one takes strings and the other takes numbers. Does VBA know what a std::string is?

Comment: It doesn't, remarkable that it works at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious problem is that the C++ code uses C++ classes which are not valid for interop. There is simply no way for the VBA marshaller to provide a std::string. Only use simple POD types for interop.

On the C++ side, for the string parameters, receive pointers to null terminated character arrays, const char*. Since std::string has a constructor that accepts const char* it is simple to adapt such a parameter to your needs.

On the VBA side you declare the string parameters as by value string, and the VBA marshaller will convert to char*. You already do this so the only changes you need are in the C++ code.

Comment: That's it!  Working fine now.  Interesting, I wouldn't have expected the marshaller to lack `std::string` but be able to provide `char*`.  Where can I find a list of the C++ classes that the VBA marshaller can provide?

Comment: Integer types, floating point types, pointers to those simple types, structs containing those simple types. Remember that std::string is only standardised in its interface. Implementations all differ. So VBA can not provide that which has many differing forms.

Comment: Weird that `char*` is used; you'd expect `WCHAR*`.

Comment: @MSalters I don't think older versions of classic VB are very, er, Unicode aware.